# change event is fired on page load It shoud not fire on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // List of contributors quantities inputs
        var honorCont   = $('.honor-contributor input[type="number"]');
        var premCont    = $('.premium-contributor input[type="number"]');
        var plusCont    = $('.plus-contributor input[type="number"]');
        var adultCont   = $('.adult-contributor input[type="number"]');
        var kidCont     = $('.kid-contributor input[type="number"]');
        var honorContPrevNum,  premContPrevNum, plusContPrevNum, adultContPrevNum, kidContPrevNum;
        honorContPrevNum = premContPrevNum = plusContPrevNum = adultContPrevNum = kidContPrevNum = 0;


        // Hide the titles on DOM load
        $('.honor-cont, .t-size, .prem-cont, .plus-cont, .adult-cont, .kid-cont').addClass('hide');

        /* Honor contributor */
        $(honorCont).change(function (){
            var honorContUpdatedNum = honorCont.val();
            if( honorContUpdatedNum > honorContPrevNum && honorContUpdatedNum > 1 ) {
                gfRepeater_repeatRepeater(4, 1);
            } else {
                gfRepeater_unrepeatRepeater(4, 1);
            }
            if( honorContUpdatedNum > 0 ){
                $('.honor-cont').removeClass('hide');
            }
            else{
                $('.honor-cont').addClass('hide');
            }
            honorContPrevNum = honorContUpdatedNum;

        });

        /* Premium contributor */
        $(premCont).change(function (){
            var premContUpdatedNum = premCont.val();
            if( premContUpdatedNum > premContPrevNum && premContUpdatedNum > 1 ) {
                gfRepeater_repeatRepeater(4, 2);
            } else {
                gfRepeater_unrepeatRepeater(4, 2);
            }
            if( premContUpdatedNum > 0 ){
                $('.prem-cont').removeClass('hide');
            }
            else{
                $('.prem-cont').addClass('hide');
            }
            premContPrevNum = premContUpdatedNum;
        });

        /* Plus contributor */
        $(plusCont).change(function () {
            var plusContUpdatedNum = plusCont.val();
            if( plusContUpdatedNum > plusContPrevNum && plusContUpdatedNum > 1 ){
                gfRepeater_repeatRepeater(4, 3);
            } else {
                gfRepeater_unrepeatRepeater(4, 3);
            }
            if( plusContUpdatedNum > 0 ){
                $('.plus-cont').removeClass('hide');
            }
            else{
                $('.plus-cont').addClass('hide');
            }
            plusContPrevNum = plusContUpdatedNum;

        });

        /* Adult contributor */
        $(adultCont).change(function () {
            var adultContUpdatedNum = adultCont.val();
            if( adultContUpdatedNum > adultContPrevNum && adultContUpdatedNum > 1 ) {
                gfRepeater_repeatRepeater(4, 4);
            } else {
                gfRepeater_unrepeatRepeater(4, 4);
            }
            if( adultContUpdatedNum > 0 ){
                $('.adult-cont').removeClass('hide');
            }
            else{
                $('.adult-cont').addClass('hide');
            }
            adultContPrevNum = adultContUpdatedNum;

        });

        /* Kid contributor */
        $(kidCont).change(function () {
            var kidContUpdatedNum = kidCont.val();
            if( kidContUpdatedNum > kidContPrevNum && kidContUpdatedNum > 1 ) {
                gfRepeater_repeatRepeater(4, 5);
            } else {
                gfRepeater_unrepeatRepeater(4, 5);
            }
            if( kidContUpdatedNum > 0 ){
                $('.kid-cont').removeClass('hide');
            }
            else{
                $('.kid-cont').addClass('hide');
            }
            kidContPrevNum = kidContUpdatedNum;

        });


    });
</script>
```

But when the page is load, i get this error:
[image]

When I debug this, I saw that the first change event is fire on page load, when it should fire only after the input type is change, I guess this related somehow to the error. Any idea why this is happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the generated javascript without the PHP tags?

Comment: What line is trigerring the error?

Comment: line 648 @BartolomeuS.Gusella

Comment: and what line is the 648? @Avishay

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is in your function. You are passing argument and you should enclose it in commas like: `gfRepeater_repeatRepeater("<?php echo $als_campaign_form_id; ?>", 1);`

Try to put commas in all functions and then check. Thanks

Comment: What actually your function **gfRepeater_repeatRepeater** is doing? Actually, need to debug w.r.t to the function.

Comment: It's a function belongs to wordpress gravity forms's ad-on called gravity form repeater field, which allows the users to add/remove fields using arrows. You also can do programmley using js functions. This function take form ID as the first argument, and field ID as the second, and whenever it called it adds the relevant field.